# How to restrict account access temporarily ubuntu

Tags: ssh, online-accounts, lock

I need to temporarily lock accounts for couple of users on my Ubuntu server. What would be the best way to do this? Reason for doing this is a maintenance. However for some users the accounts need to be opened the whole time. So my question is how to lock out some users so they cannot ssh into their accounts without messing with their passwords.

best

b

Answer (score 1):

From the `passwd` man page:

> ```
>    -l, --lock
>        Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a
>        password by changing it to a value which matches no possible
>        encrypted value (it adds a '!' at the beginning of the password).
>
>        Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be
>        able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key).
>        To disable the account, administrators should use usermod
>        --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).
>
>        Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their
>        password.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the one of the following directives: `DenyUsers DenyGroups AllowUsers AllowGroups`

With `DenyUsers` you can blacklist specific users and with `AllowUsers` you can whitelist them. Works the same way with groups.